# All non editor panels are muted/hard to read with Dark Themes in Pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I was using the `High Contrast` Theme happily for a few weeks now. The only downside is when pasting screenshots: it is hard to read the images. So I (briefly) went to `Github` theme.  After switching back to `High Contrast` the non-editor panels are muted and hard to read:

[image]

Concerned but not defeated I tried out the other dark themes including `Darcula` and `Monokai`. They had the same behavior.  More concerned I quit Pycharm and restarted. Always a good idea in troubleshooting!  But .. no dice *this* time.

Any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had been using the `Switcher for choosing a different`Theme`. That apparently is *buggy* ..

Using the `Preferences` fixed the problem

[image]